# (Done!) Table and text styles error in this book project

Tags: tables, fonts, tabularx, displaystyle, installing-fonts

(Resolved)

I'm in trouble again on this project.
It is a book, with standard dimensions of A5 paper (14x21 cm). And I need help.

The project is here: https://www.overleaf.com/1332517788tpyfvfrnnsqd (to read all lines).

1. Most importantly: I searched a lot and didn't find a solution. How to decrease table spacing with exaggerated spaces. Does not fit on the page
   [image: Error table]

1.2 I will use table and "frame" (apper "quadro"), how should I show "Table 1.1" in the text? Thus:
[image: Model - goal.]

2. I can't change (control the choice) of font style.
   I would like to choose one of these: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/
   This one: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/qtagatetype/

[image: Font style]

3. The spacing between lines of text, how can I change it?

Thank you for your attention,
Greetings

Comment: Please, provide MWE here, in your question. And, please one problem per question.

Comment: Owwww I'm so sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, next time ask separate questions.

**(1)** Change the line spacing using `\setstretch`. For example `\setstretch{1.25}` is a good choice for a book. Go back to normal with `\setstretch{1.0}`.

[image: c2]

**(2)** For the table use `tabularx` (see code bellow)

[image: T]

**(3)** To use the font you liked must use `xelatex` or `lualatex` and replace

`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with

```
\usepackage{fontspec} % added <<<<
\setmainfont{QTAgateType}[SizeFeatures={Size=8},]
```

This is the complete code

```
    % !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[10pt,fleqn]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations

\usepackage[top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm,left=1.91cm,right=1.91cm,headsep=10pt,a5paper]{geometry} % Page margins
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum} % Required for specifying colors by name
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{51,102,0} 
\definecolor{lightgray}{RGB}{229,229,229} 
% Font Settings
\usepackage{avant} % Use the Avantgarde font for headings
%\usepackage{times} % Use the Times font for headings
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Use the Adobe Times Roman as the default text font together with math symbols from the Sym­bol, Chancery and Com­puter Modern fonts

\setlength\columnsep{43pt} % This is the default columnsep for all pages
%\columnsep{10pt} 
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics

\usepackage{fontspec} % added <<<<
\setmainfont{QTAgateType}[SizeFeatures={Size=8},]

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs

\usepackage{verbatim}

% autor a la derecha en poema
\usepackage{ragged2e}
% MATHS PACKAGE
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand*{\horzbar}{\rule[0.05ex]{2.5ex}{0.5pt}}
\usepackage{calc}

% VERBATIM PACKAGE
\usepackage{verbatim}

% Bibliography
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % BibTeX bibliography file
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}

\input{structure} % Insert the commands.tex file which contains the majority of the structure behind the template

\begin{document}

\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(5,5){\includegraphics[scale=1.8]{xx.jpg}}} % Image background
\centering
\vspace*{3cm}
\par\normalfont\fontsize{35}{35}\sffamily\selectfont
\textbf{\textcolor{black}{CINELEE}}\\
{\LARGE }\par % Book title
\vspace*{1cm}
{\Huge \fcolorbox{black}{white}{ANGIE TATIANA MOLANO GUZMÁN} }\par
\vspace*{14cm}
{\huge \fcolorbox{black}{white}{\textbf{\textsc{Editorial Maguen David}}} }
% Author name
\endgroup

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COPYRIGHT PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\afterpage{\null\newpage}
\newpage
~\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}


\afterpage{\null\newpage}
\onecolumn
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{5cm}
\Huge{\textbf{CINELLE\\}}
\vspace*{3cm}
\huge{\textbf{Angie Tatiana Molano Guzmán\\}}
\vspace*{7cm}
\huge{\textsc{Editorial Maguen David}}
\end{center}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
~\vfill
%\noindent Copyright \copyright\ 2014 Andrea Hidalgo\\ % Copyright notice
%\small
\noindent \textsc{CINELEE}\\\\
\noindent \textsc{Estudiante Universidad Pedagógica Nacional:}  \textit{Angie Tatiana Molano Guzmán}\\
\noindent \textsc{Asesoría pedagógica y editorial:} Docente Universidad Pedagógica Nacional \textit{Leonardo Cano}\\ % License information
\noindent \textsc{Asesoría gráfica:} \textit{Daniel Siervo}\\ % License information
\noindent Publicado en Noviembre de 2017 \\\\ % Printing/edition date 

\noindent \textsc{\textbf{Editorial Maguen David}}\\\\
\noindent \textbf{\small{Todo el material que aparece en la Unidad Didáctica Cinlee está protegido por las Leyes de Propiedad Intelectual vigentes.}}\\\\
\noindent\small{ \textbf{Copyright \copyright\ 2017 Unidad Didáctica Cinelee. Todos los derechos reservados. No se copiará, fotocopiará, reproducirá, traducirá o reducirá con cualquier tipo de medio electrónico o formato legible por máquina, ninguno de los materiales disponibles en la Unidad Didáctica Cinlee, en su totalidad o en parte, sin el consentimiento previo por escrito de la autora Angie Tatiana Molano G.. Toda reproducción, en la forma que se produjese, y sin el permiso de la autora Angie Tatiana Molano G. queda prohibida. Queda asimismo prohibida su distribución con fines comerciales.}}
\large
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLE OF CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\chapterimage{pano-5.jpg} % heading image

\pagestyle{empty} % No headers

\renewcommand\contentsname{Tabla de Contenido}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliographie}
\tableofcontents% Print the table of contents itself

%\cleardoublepage % Forces the first chapter to start on an odd page so it's on the right

\pagestyle{fancy} % Print headers again

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\chapterimage{pano-5.jpg} % Chapter heading image

\chapter{Bogotá mi ciudad \\ Utilizarás adecuadamente \\ los conectores lógicos \\ Analizarás una película}

\section{En el fondo de un poema}\index{poema}
\setstretch{1.25}
\hspace{1em}Las figuras retóricas, también llamadas figuras literarias, representan una manera diferente de utilizar el lenguaje. La finalidad de estas figuras es crear un estilo comunicativo más original, más literario. Las Figuras Retóricas ayudan a captar la atención, sorprenden por su originalidad y poseen un gran poder sugerente y persuasivo permitiendo una comunicación más eficaz. En español existen más de cien figuras retóricas y muchas de ellas son variantes de una misma idea. Las más conocidas son: metáfora, sinonimia, hipérbole, paradoja e ironía. El siguiente poema tiene como título “Lista negra” y se encuentran en el libro País Secreto (1988) del autor Juan Manuel Roca. Realiza una primera lectura de este para después realizar una taller relacionado con este. 

Hago la lista negra de mis dudas en medio de un país diezmado y no sé si las cartas que no llegan son violadas como el sueño o las mujeres... (Al amanecer arrecia la lluvia y acaso la tormenta acalle disparos lejanos...). No sé, exactamente, si algún hombre en mi país es buscado en la ciudad con la oculta lámpara de algún ladrón de sueños... (Alguien al borde de un abismo acaso inicie el retrato hablado de un ángel...). Y cuando llega la noche o entro al sueño como a un tren que me saca de un país oscuro, pienso si algún oculto guardián decidiera aplicarme la ley de fuga de los sueños…
    
    %******************************** changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
    \begin{table}[!htp]
        \footnotesize
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \caption{Métodos de previsão de demanda, classificação e finalidade.}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X|>{\hsize=.5\hsize}Y |X|}
        \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
    \textbf{ Meta} & \textbf{ Classification} & \textbf{Final} \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
     Review Submit &  History &  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut puruselit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictumgravida mauris. \\
    \hline
     Estimativa de força de vendas &  History & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut puruselit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictumgravida mauris. \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
    Review Submit & History & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut puruselit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictumgravida mauris. Nam arcu libero,nonummy eget, consectetuer id,vulputate a, magna.\\
    \hline
     Média móvel simples &  History & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut puruselit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictumgravida mauris. Nam arcu libero,nonummy eget, consectetuer id,vulputate a, magna. \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
     Review Submit &  History & Nam arcu libero,nonummy eget, consectetuer id,vulputate a, magna. Donec vehiculaaugue eu neque. Pellentesque habitantmorbi tristique senectus et netus etmalesuada fames ac turpis egestas.Mauris ut leo.\\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption*{Fonte: kdfds  sdgssdgd}
    \end{table}


\hspace{1em}Las figuras retóricas, también llamadas figuras literarias, representan una manera diferente de utilizar el lenguaje. La finalidad de estas figuras es crear un estilo comunicativo más original, más literario. Las Figuras Retóricas ayudan a captar la atención, sorprenden por su originalidad y poseen un gran poder sugerente y persuasivo permitiendo una comunicación más eficaz. En español existen más de cien figuras retóricas y muchas de ellas son variantes de una misma idea. Las más conocidas son: metáfora, sinonimia, hipérbole, paradoja e ironía. El siguiente poema tiene como título “Lista negra” y se encuentran en el libro País Secreto (1988) del autor Juan Manuel Roca. Realiza una primera lectura de este para después realizar una taller relacionado con este. \\

Hago la lista negra de mis dudas en medio de un país diezmado y no sé si las cartas que no llegan son violadas como el sueño o las mujeres... (Al amanecer arrecia la lluvia y acaso la tormenta acalle disparos lejanos...). No sé, exactamente, si algún hombre en mi país es buscado en la ciudad con la oculta lámpara de algún ladrón de sueños... (Alguien al borde de un abismo acaso inicie el retrato hablado de un ángel...). Y cuando llega la noche o entro al sueño como a un tren que me saca de un país oscuro, pienso si algún oculto guardián decidiera aplicarme la ley de fuga de los sueños…

\subsection*{Instrucción}
Teniendo en cuenta los talleres de las sesiones anteriores y la relación entre la película y el poema, realiza un texto argumentativo o un cuento donde se evidencia tu postura y opinión sobre: pobreza, drogas, violencia, posibilidades de trabajo y sueños en los habitantes de la ciudad de Bogotá. Ten en cuenta las siguientes indicaciones:

\begin{itemize}
\item Extensión: 3 - 4 párrafos
\item Escrito a mano o digital
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

**Must use xelatex or lulatex to compile**, instead of pdflatex.

Or use another font that not require `fontspec`. (See `Usage` in the Font Catalogue)

[image: Must]

Comment: <3 
Thank sooo much!!!! \o/

Comment: @Marcio Lord You need to use xelatex or lualatex instead of pdflatex. Or choose another font that does not need `fontspec`. In the catalog look the section Usage.

Comment: Ok. But I don't know how to use =(

Comment: @Marcio Lord Ask a the question.

Answer (score 2):

An option for table layout. By using `tabularray` package amd reduce `baselineskip` in tables' texts:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{My caption with desired format.}
     \centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={X[1,l] X[0.8,l] X[4.2,j]},
             colsep={4pt},
             row{1}={font=\bfseries, bg=gray7},
             row{even}={gray9},
             rows={font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}
             }
Meta    
    &   Clasification   
        &  Final            \\
Review Submit
    &   History
        &   \lipsum[66]     \\
Estimativa de forca de vendas
    &   History
        &   \lipsum[66]     \\
Review Submit
    &   History
        &   \lipsum[66]     \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great!!!!! Thank u so much!!!!

Comment: Not find #tabularray and now?

Comment: @MarcioLord, where you looking for it? In Overleaf? It hasn't installed yet (as far as I know), so you need to do this yourself. Ask their support how to do this (I'm not use it, so I'm not familiar with it). Otherwise, package is available on CTAN (https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray?lang=en).